# if statement not executing correctly based on return type of argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

This is a very basic question, so hopefully a solid answer is out there somewhere.

I've been working with Core Data for the past 3 weeks and finally have a nice chunk of code to handle 5 objects across 300 levels, broken down into 4 kinds of levels.  Let's call these kinds of levels `typeOfLevel` (they are `NSNumber`'s).

In short, my predicate for the fetch request says "if the combination of level X and type Y are not found, start setting certain objects".  Well, what if I've already set `typeOfLevel` but my `level` object hasn't been set yet (because I've never actually played that level before)......I certainly don't want to keep setting `typeOfLevel` over and over again.  So here's what I wrote:

```
    if (![_levelInformation valueForKey:@"typeOfLevel"]) {
         [_levelInformation setValue:typeNumber forKey:@"typeOfLevel"];
         NSLog(@"Got here");
    }
```

`_levelInformation` is my data model object (which I have tested, and is verified to contain values for the level and best move count (that I incorporate)). `typeNumber` is an `NSNumber` object that contains the value of what type of level I'm on.  I also have verified the existence of this value through debugging.

My thought process is, if the argument in the `if` statement is false (if there is no value for the key `typeOfLevel`, then set one.  This, in my mind, should only ever run once so long as my store hasn't been reset.  This statement gets executed every single time I run this.  `typeOfLevel` always gets set no matter what.  Why is this?  How can I make it only set itself once?

Comment: Do you save the model object after setting this property?

Comment: Yes, that's not the issue.  The argument in the if statement seems to not understand that there is already a value for `typeOfLevel`.  It could be 2 but the if statement won't work.

Comment: have you tried NSLog before levelInformation? just to see what it outputs

Comment: Yes, everything works.  So, before I posted the question, I got rid of the `if` statement and just put `[_levelInformation setValue:typeNumber forKey:@"typeOfLevel"];` and I was able to store a value for `typeOfLevel` for each successive run of my app (no matter how many levels I tried for whatever type).

Comment: The only way to enter the body of the `if` statement is for `[_levelInformation valueForKey:@"typeOfLevel"]` to be `nil`.  The code you've posted does not give enough information to tell you why this would be the case.